# Deduct transaction fee always from 1 receiver address if sending some BTC amount to 2 different receiver addresses in single transaction

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees, sending, receiving

Need help!! anyone there..
How to Deduct transaction fee always from 1 receiver address if sending some BTC amount to 2 different receiver addresses in single transaction

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of 'which address is paying the fee' in a Bitcoin transaction.

Instead, transactions are constructed as follows:

- One or more UTXOs are specified as inputs. These UTXOs are spent in their entirety
- New UTXOs are created as outputs. Each one is of a certain value, and pays to a certain address.
- The difference (value of inputs - value of outputs) is the implied miner's fee.

So, it is up to whoever crafts the transaction to allocate Bitcoin to each newly created output in a way which satisfies the socially agreed upon transaction conditions (ie, *"decide who is paying the fee, and then deduct the fee from the newly created output they will own"*).